# Ant 1.10.1 version throwing java unsupported class version error

Tags: java, ant

I have installed ANT on my machine , I have set the environment variables for ANT_HOME , when i am trying to test the ant installation through command window console by providing the below command 
ant -v
I am getting the below error

`enter code here`C:\Users\XXXXXX>ant -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/to
ols/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

But i have checked the JDK version and JRE Version , both seems to be the same . PFB the output of the versions respectively

C:\Users\XXXXX>java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

C:\Users\XXXXX>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80

Compiler versions and run time versions both are same , what could be the issue here

Comment: Isn't 52.0 a Java 8 compiled class? In which case, the report of Java 7 would indicate you need to update to Java 8. Edit: Ant 1.10.x requires Java 8 runtime. See the requirements at ant.apache.org.

Comment: yes thats correct , initially i installed it jdk version 8 and then uninstalled and restarted my laptop and then installed jdk version 7 again , many of my existing applications were using only jdk 7

Comment: You still have multiple versions of Java installed somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

According to the (current) [ant home page](http://%3Ca%20href=%22http://ant.apache.org/%22%3E)

> The Apache Ant team currently maintains two lines of development. The 1.9.x releases require Java5 at runtime and 1.10.x requires Java8 at runtime

You'll need Java 8.